# Blender Cycles render-> Different result between screen image and saved jpg file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Render screen image is different than saved file.

Any way to correct it ?[image]

Comment: It probably has to do with your samples (eg. preview vs. render)

Comment: It is not a preview render. It is a Render Result window on the left. Please, see footer image.

Comment: Check out the answer here then [complements of troy_s](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35722/when-to-use-srgb-and-when-not-to/35854#35854)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: OSX Preferences/Screen]

I have changed my Preferences/Screen to sRGB color profile. So, Blender and OS X use same color profile