# Different lighting between saved render image and CompositorNodeViewer image data?

Tags: python, scripting, eevee-render-engine

I am following this blog post for testing out rendering possibly without writing to a file:
https://ammous88.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/blender-access-render-results-pixels-directly-from-python-2/

I've tried this procedure out on a custom scene, but noticed the lighting was significantly different. Trying it out on a public demo, the [Race Spaceship](https://download.blender.org/demo/eevee/race_spaceship/race_spaceship.blend), I also observe a difference between the image from the saved file from `render()` (`img_file`) and the file from the view data (`img_view`), computed as `np.abs(img_file - img_view)`:

[image: img diff]

Any chance someone knows the root cause of this?

Here's the script I'm using to create this image (Blender 2.80, Ubuntu 18.04):
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/blender_server/blob/625f30f191d315fb741b88c817094ecd104eeaa6/view_rendering_test.py

Possibly related: <s>is that the Viewer node data is using sRGB, whereas I want to see RGB</s>?

[Blender Cycles render-> Different result between screen image and saved jpg file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48600/blender-cycles-render-different-result-between-screen-image-and-saved-jpg-file)
(will see if I can tinker with settings to affect this)

Comment: Might be post-processing dither in the saved image

Comment: Thanks! Looked at the `Scene > Post Processing` section, the Dither value is set to 0, and Compositing is checked. However, if I manually render via the GUI (after running the script) and save both the `Render Result` and `Viewer Result` images, I do get the same output, so it seems like it may be a difference in file I/O, but it's still unclear what exactly. If I then open up the scripting panel, execute just the image extract, I still need the `np.clip` since some of the RGB channels fall outside of the range of `[0..1]`.